# Spring Boot Maven build offline when machine has no internet connectivity

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project that uses Maven. The problem is that I need to build the application as a Jar on a machine that doesn't have internet connectivity.

I have tried downloading all dependencies and copying across my .m2 folder from my Mac over to the machine with no network, but Maven still won't build the project, as it throws up an error such as this;

```
mvn -o package

Non-resolveable parent POM for com.domain.visualisation: Cannot access central https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in offline mode and the artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE has not bee downloaded from it before.
```

Is there a way to get this working without internet connectivity?

Comment: You need to have all the necessary artifacts, including parent poms and so on. The easiest way is to build with internet connection, then copy the `.m2/repository" folder to the desired location and build with offline flag.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: In your error, the artifact `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE` is mentioned. Did you check whether this artifact is present or not?

Comment: It's not there. Why would Maven has not downloaded it?

Comment: I would try again. Make sure that you build the project (like `clean package`) on the machine with internet connection, then move the project and the `.m2/repository` to the machine without internet, and then try again with offline mode. Make sure you have the very same revision of the project on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

If You are sure all the dependencies are inside your local m2 folder, _remote.repositories files might be the reason for this error. Search and remove every `_remote.repositories` file inside local m2 folder and try your build again.